# How to access non-public fields and inheritent fields in scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a piece of code as below

```
object TestReflection {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val cls = Class.forName("test.Child")
    cls.getDeclaredField("w")
    cls.getDeclaredField("x")
   cls.getDeclaredField("z")
  }
}

class Parent(val x : Int, val t : Int) {

}
class Child(x : Int, z : Int, val w : Int) extends Parent(x, 0) {

}
```

Seems that both cls.getDeclaredField("x") and cls.getDeclaredField("z") don't wok. Anyone know how to access them correctly ?

Thanks

Comment: I can access x now by calling parent class's method :
field = cls.getSuperclass.getDeclaredField("x")
but still not sure how to get value of "z" if we don't make it to val

Comment: In `Child`, `z` is not a field but a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x and z in Child are not variables, they are constructor parameters (i.e. they remain only for the construction and not part of the constructed object) and therefore you cannot access them.

You can access field = cls.getSuperclass.getDeclaredField("x") because x is defined as val in the super class but this is NOT the x in the construction but instead an x inherited from the parent.

To access z you need to assign it to something which survives construction.